# Transistor control through opamp

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, circuit-analysis

In the  given circuit I want to compute the current going through R3 given the current of Rs (Rs is a shunt resistor.)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUEgYt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is Iout in terms of Isense ?

Comment: School assignment? What have you figured out so far? Which part you did not understand so we can focus on that instead of something you already know.

Comment: no, it is not  school asignment, it is  a circuit used battery current charging circuit by "linear technology application note an68f page 16/36"  and the circuit used to program the charging current of the battery. I want to get the equation of Iout in terms of Isense

Comment: The negative feedback makes the positive and negative terminals have the same voltage. Also no current is going in the negative and positive terminals due to the high input impedance. This means no voltage drop across R1 and R2. Hence V+ = 0.1 Isense = V-. The current through the emitter resistor is then V-/200 = 0.1 Isense / 200 = 0.0005 Isense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This circuit consists of two cascaded dual circuits - current-to-voltage converter (Rs) and voltage-to-current converter (the op-amp, Q1 and R3). So it is a current-to-current converter... current amplifier... current attenuator or, if the output current is equal to the input one, the so-called *current mirror*.

Simply speaking, the input current creates a voltage drop Vs = IIN.Rs across Rs and the op-amp follower copy this voltage across R3 by the help of the output (collector) current IOUT. So IOUT.R3 = IIN.Rs -> IOUT = IN.Rs/R3 = IIN/2000, i.e., the circuit is a current attenuator.

The clever trick of this circuit solution is that the emitter follower (Q1) is put in the feedback loop and the op-amp compensates the transistor base-emitter voltage VBE. For this purpose, the op amp "lifts" its output voltage with VBE; so the emitter voltage is equal to the input voltage (across Rs). Thus the combination of the op-amp and emitter-follower can be considered as a perfect voltage follower working on the resistive load R3... i.e., perfect voltage-to-current converter (current sink).

It is interesting to see that both resistors Rs and R3 act as current-to-voltage converters (V = I.R) but the function of R3 is "reversed" by the negative feedback... and it acts as the dual voltage-to-current converter (I = V/R). This is a fundamental property of negative feedback systems. The op-amp non-inverting amplifier is another example of this unique feature where the attenuating voltage divider is made to act as an "amplifying voltage divider".

The resistors R1 and R2 do not play any role since the op-amp inputs have high resistance and should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it is very helpful, but I did not understand what you meant in the 3rd paragraph, can you explain more please ??

Comment: The op-amp behaves here as a "living being". It's task is to keep the voltage across R3 equal to the input voltage across Rs. But some of this voltage (0.7V) is lost on the base-emitter junction. As the op-amp "observes" the voltage after the loss (at the emitter) by its inverting input, it "feels" something is wrong... and begins to compensate it by increasing its output voltage untilt equalizes VR3 with Vin. All we act in this way in life when realizing our goals...

Answer (score 1):

The Op Amp is acting a voltage follower, with a gain of 1 at the Emitter of Q1. Therefore the same voltage that appears on Rs will be impressed on R3.

Ohm's law says that I = V/R, so the ratio of Iout to Isense will be the inverse of the resistance ratio, ie. Rs/R3 = 0.1/200 = 500uA/A.